# Why does Data(bytes:count:) require a mutable variable as the source for its pointer?

Tags: swift, pointers, buffer

Given this code sample,

```swift
var int = 1
let intData = Data(bytes: &int, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: Int.self))
```

I do not understand why the initializer cannot accept an immutable variable declared with `let`, i.e.,

```swift
let int = 1
let intData = Data(bytes: &int, count: MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: int)) // Cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'int' is a 'let' constant
```

I do not understand, because my expectation of the initializer would be to copy the data from the pointer, rather than use it as a mutable buffer.

The documentation provided specifically says,

```
init(bytes: UnsafeRawPointer, count: Int)
  Creates data with copied memory content.
```

Can someone please explain?

Comment: The error you posted and the method documentation you showed don't match up. The error is complaining about an `inout` parameter, but the method whose documentation you posted doesn't have any `inout` parameters`.

Comment: Also, you have a serious bug: `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: Int.self)` is getting you the size of the metatype of `Int` (`Int.self`). Given that you're trying to create a data from an `Int`, and not from the metatype of `Int`, you need either `MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: int)` or `MemoryLayout<Int>.size`

Comment: That is the correct documentation. Thanks for pointing out the other issue.

Comment: Not really my area of expertise but according to the documentation you are using _implicit bridging_ to pass a pointer by using `&int`, and for this bridging the parameter is treated as an `inout` parameter and for that kind of parameter you must `var` declare your variable. This was more of a conclusion than an explanation but maybe it helps.

Comment: That makes sense. It works using let using the array bridging syntax `Data(bytes: [value], count: MemoryLayout<Int>.size)`.